# GridSplitter inside Expander expanding beyond a height

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a expander which contains a grid in which I have a grid splitter.

The Document Outline and UI is like this

[image]

and here is the code.

```
<Grid x:Name="TopGrid" ShowGridLines="True" >
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="150"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="200" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Expander x:Name="CompanyDescriptionExpander" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" IsExpanded="True" Background="Black" >
  <Expander.Header>
   <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=CompanyDescriptionExpander, 
                         Path=ActualWidth}" Background="Aquamarine">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Expander Header" Foreground="Black" />
   </Grid>
  </Expander.Header>
   <Expander.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="DescriptionGrid" MaxHeight="130" ShowGridLines="True">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="120"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="4" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="10"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Background="Orange" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
              MinHeight="40" MaxHeight="120" x:Name="DescriptionText"
              Text="TextBlock Content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
     <Button x:Name="SaveIconButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" 
             Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     <Button x:Name="CancelIconButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="20" 
             Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     <GridSplitter ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" ResizeDirection="Rows" 
                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   Height="10" MaxHeight="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" />
    </Grid>
   </Expander.Content>
 </Expander>
 <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="20" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Green" />
</Grid>
```

When we use grid splitter it expands

[image]

But it goes on even after textbox reaches its maximum height and gridsplitter goes behind button(green).

My problem scenario can be replicated copying my code in a project

[image]

I want that it should stop when textbox reaches its maximum height.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DescriptionGrid change the second rows MaxHeight from 120 to 95.

The combined max height of the three rows in that grid exceeds the max height of the grid itself.